# Ionic2 / Angular2 Forms With FormGroup For Nested Components

Tags: ionic2, angular2-forms

In `Ionic2` / `Angular2`, I'm struggling to get `FormGroup` and `FormGroupName` working with nested `Components`, keep getting errors like.

```
Cannot find control with path: 'location -> latitude'
```

The `Form` page renders a dynamic list of fields.

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="postForm()">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let field of fields">
      <field-location [field]="field" [formGroup]="formGroup" *ngIf="field.input == 'location'"></field-location>
      <!-- OTHER FIELD TYPES HERE  -->
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</form>
```

The `Form` class creates the `FormGroup` and `FormControl` items in `ionViewDidLoad`.

```
this.formGroup = new FormGroup({});
for (let index in this.fields) {
  let field = this.fields[index];
  if (field.input == 'location') {
    this.formGroup.addControl(field.key, new FormGroup({
       latitude: new FormControl(''),
       longitude: new FormControl('')}));
  }
  else {
    this.formGroup.addControl(attribute.key, new FormControl(''));
  }
}
```

The `Location` class defines `field` and `formGroup` as inputs.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'field-location',
  templateUrl: 'location.html',
  inputs: ['field', 'formGroup']
})
export class LocationComponent {
    field: any = {};
    formGroup: FormGroup;
    constructor() {
  }
}
```

The `Location` view takes the `FormGroup` as an `Input` and uses the field `Key` as the `formGroupName`.

```
<ion-item [formGroup]="formGroup" *ngIf="formGroup">
  <ion-label>{{field.label}}</ion-label>
  <div [formGroupName]="field.key">
    <ion-input type="text" hidden [formControlName]="latitude"></ion-input>
    <ion-input type="text" hidden [formControlName]="longitude"></ion-input>
  </div>
</ion-item>
```

How do you get `formGroupName` to work in nested `Components`? To you need to also pass the nested `FormGroup` in from the parent?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem, so sharing the solution in case it helps others.

Looks like the issue was related to binding on `[formControlName]="latitude"`.

```
<ion-item [formGroup]="formGroup" *ngIf="formGroup">
  <ion-label>{{field.label}}</ion-label>
  <div [formGroupName]="field.key">
    <ion-input type="text" hidden [formControlName]="latitude"></ion-input>
    <ion-input type="text" hidden [formControlName]="longitude"></ion-input>
  </div>
</ion-item>
```

But it should just have been `formControlName="latitude"`.

```
<ion-item [formGroup]="formGroup" *ngIf="formGroup">
  <ion-label>{{field.label}}</ion-label>
  <div [formGroupName]="field.key">
    <ion-input type="text" hidden formControlName="latitude"></ion-input>
    <ion-input type="text" hidden formControlName="longitude"></ion-input>
  </div>
</ion-item>
```

After making this change, the nested `Component` works as expected. Hope this helps someone else!